# How can I redirect my website without messing up the existing mail server setup?

Tags: email, redirect, dns

This is the situation I am facing right now. Hope someone can help me out with the circumstance. Great thanks.

I am trying to redirect my existing website to another website. I can be able to do it by changing the DNS setting from my domain holding panel. But the problem is that there is mail service setup on the old website (e.g. user@olddomain.com), once I change the DNS setting to redirect the old domain to new domain, the mail service is dead. However, I want to keep the mail server using the old domain.

Anyway that I can redirect the domain but keep the mail server at the old domain. I am newbie to this server setup procedure. Thanks for any help provided

Comment: Just to make sure, since it affects the answer: do you want to redirect existing website to another website or you want to move the existing site (for your domain) to another hosting provider (so keeping the same domain name)?

Comment: Dear Dusan, I am trying to redirect the site as the information is no longer updated and necessary. However, I want to keep the domain so I am trying to do redirecting. The problem I discovered is that there is mailbox service under my old domain (user@olddomain.com), once I redirect the whole site, the existing mail server down. I think it is because redirecting the site makes everything pointing to the new server where there is no mail service.

Comment: That should be fairly simple, but can you show your existing DNS settings (you can replace real domain name with `example.com`), especially `MX` and `www` related `A` or `CNAME` records

Comment: I am kind of newbie. The MX DNS setting part, where can I change that? In the cPanel?

Comment: Changing/adding DNS records is (usually) done through some kind of web console offered by your DNS provider (that is usually either place where you registered your domain name, or place where you are hosting your website)